# I need a Common function to fill combobox using stored procedure in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I need a common method for filling combobox from database with a default value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question seems way broad. Have you tried _anything_ to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times as a start..

Comment: Note that in a well-designed program, the same code that loads data from the database will not be the same code that populates the combobox. Learn about Separation-of-Concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method....I think this will help you

```
    public bool fillComboBox(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox combobox, string procedureName, string dTable, string dDisplay, string dValue, string defaultValue)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter sqladp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection _sqlconTeam = new SqlConnection(DBCon.conStr))
            {
                sqlcmd.Connection = _sqlconTeam;
                sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcmd.CommandText = procedureName;
                _sqlconTeam.Open();
                sqladp.SelectCommand = sqlcmd;
                sqladp.Fill(ds, dTable);
                DataRow nRow = ds.Tables[dTable].NewRow();
                nRow[dDisplay] = defaultValue;
                nRow[dValue] = "-1";
                ds.Tables[dTable].Rows.InsertAt(nRow, 0);
                combobox.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[dTable].DefaultView;
                combobox.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[dTable].Columns[1].ToString();
                combobox.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[dTable].Columns[0].ToString();
                combobox.SelectedIndex = 0;

            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            sqladp.Dispose();
            sqlcmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
```